# Grabbing protected content through cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm currently developing a Dashboard for users that grabs graph data from another site. To get this graph, it requires you to be logged in.

The form I'm attempting to replicate contains this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://redacted/auth/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="loginform" name="loginform"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xyxRW0w8ZjHyP7ZvrCFygqcNkPZ37P35wh8NifuC">
    <table class="form spaceform">
        <tr>
            <td class='label'><label for="email">Email address:</label></td>
            <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'></td>
            <td>
                <input id="has_account_new" name="has_account" type="radio" value="new">
                <label for="has_account_new">I am a new customer</label><br />
                <input id="has_account_return" checked="checked" name="has_account" type="radio" value="return">
                <label for="has_account_return">I am a returning customer</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" value="" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="https://redacted/auth/forgot">Forgot your password?</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='center' class='noborder'><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xyxRW0w8ZjHyP7ZvrCFygqcNkPZ37P35wh8NifuC">        
    <input type="hidden" name="page_transfer" value="0" />
</form>
```

and the PHP code I'm currently using to try and login and grab the graphs:

```
$username = 'demo@demo.com';
$password = 'demo';
$loginUrl = 'https://redacted/auth/login/';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&has_account=return&_token=PM2dY2hlbkPLvB97FyjL7cnPwryHXgfiex5050Iy&page_transfer=0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://redacted/ucp/view-graph/157/0/1');

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $content;
```

The current output is HTML redirecting me back to their login form which I'm guessing is because I'm missing something on the POST request. I'm also seeing tokens inside the login form which I'm unsure of, could this be something to-do with it?

Comment: Perhaps the site is using a one time pass (OTP) as the token, therefore preventing CSRF and your attempts from working. But we are not in the position to answer this—you'll have to contact the site if there is a way to authenticate users remotely. They might have an API for that, they might not.

Comment: I have permission from the owner to create the bot, they are currently developing a new panel with an API but in the meantime I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. The server may be denying any login attempt not containing a token value issued by the same server.
I suggest adding the token value to the posted fields.

Moreover, you should first `get` the login page in order to have a "fresh" token, then `post` with it. Let me add that you will probably be receiving some cookie after you do the `get`. That cookie you should send along in the `post`. I think curl does that by default if you don't close the handle.

Comment: Thanks, Ill give this a shot and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around and help from [alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3208258/alejandro) the solution was to send a GET request to the page and gather the token, this mess of code below works just fine for what I need it for.

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$rand = rand();
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://blank/auth/login',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($resp);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$token = $xpath->query('//input[@name="_token"]');
$token = $token->item(0);
$token = $token->getAttribute('value');

$username = 'blank';
$password = 'blank';
$loginUrl = 'https://blank/auth/login';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_token='.$token.'&email='.$username.'&has_account=return&password='.$password.'&_token='.$token.'&page_transfer=0');

$store = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://blank/ucp/view-graph/157/0/1');

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('bw.png', $content);

?>
```